# Nutch/Hadoop: How do I configure the url to track the job?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, nutch

I am new to Nutch and Hadoop. I followed a couple tutorials to setup nutch and hadoop for windows/eclipse. I am coming accross some errors during fetching and would like to see more information on the job but the url to track the job points to http://localhost:8080/ and I cannot access it. When I run Hadoop it runs on http://localhost:8088 and I am trying to point the tracking url to that address.

I have tried to add

```
   <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>  
     <value>127.0.0.1:8088</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>  
     <value>127.0.0.1:8088</value>
   </property>
```

to yarn-site.xml but it did not work. Could someone point me in the correct direction as to how to configure the "url to track the job" or where this information is getting pulled from?

Answer (score 0):

The currently running Yarn applications are shown on http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps/RUNNING - there should be a link to the actual Nutch job you want to track.

The port 8088 is the default (see [yarn-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)), so there should be no need to reconfigure it.

Comment: In doubt, the default port may depend on the Hadoop version used.